# Grails filter multiple actions

Tags: grails, filter

Within one filter, how can I match more than one action of the same controller?

```
def filters = {
  organisationDelete(controller: "organisation", action: "confirmDelete, delete") { 
    //...
  }
}
```

In this mapping I have "confirmDelete" as a GET and "delete" as POST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the old ACEGI plugin I could write the actions separated by comma. Though, now with Spring Security Core I have to use a pipe. So, the following solves the problem

```
action: "confirmDelete|delete"
```