# How to define multiple distinct controllers with distinct actions in Grails filter?

Tags: grails

I've read the post [on defining multiple distinct controllers in a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941249/how-to-define-multiple-distinct-controllers-in-grails-2-filter) and on the post [with multiple actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572108/grails-filter-multiple-actions) but can we combine the two? For example:

```
def filters = {
someFilterMethod(controller: 'controller1|controller2|...', action: 'controller1Action|controller2Action')         
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible? Alternatively, I could always rename both actions to the same name. But just wondering if its possible. Thanks.

Comment: This would be very simple to try out in a small test app with a few controllers.

Comment: Yup I did. The action is applied to all the specified controllers. I was hoping that I could specify a unique action for the specific controller. For example, filter is applied only to controller1/controller1Action and not have it applied to controller1/controller2Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to declaratively express something like that but it would be trivial for you to put whatever imperative logic you need inside of the filter to be more specific about which combinations of controllers and actions the filter has its effect on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like this...

```
class MyFilters {

    def filters = {
        someFilter(controller:'one|two|three', action:'read|delete|save') {
            before = {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I was looking for was that I could specify a unique action for the specific controller. For example, filter is applied only to controller1/controller1Action and not have it applied to controller1/controller2Action. With your solution, the filters would be applied to actions read|delete|save for  controller one|two|three. I was hoping filter would be applied to read for controller one, delete for controller two and save for controller three only.

Comment: There is no way to declaratively express something like that but it would be trivial for you to put whatever imperative logic you need inside of the filter to be more specific about which combinations of controllers and actions the filter has its effect on.

Comment: Thanks! Yup that's kinda what i did. If u submit that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks once again,